# Specific cloud provider libraries no longer in spring-cloud-dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

I was trying to migrate my spring boot project from spring boot 2.3 to 2.5 and spring cloud accordingly Hoxton to 2020.0.X and I noticed that the cloud provider specific libraries have been removed.

[image]

```
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws:jar is missing. @ line 56, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-messaging:jar is missing. @ line 60, column 21
```

My first guess would be to specify my aws libraries to the right version but I wonder if there is a best way to ensure that my aws libraries are updated at the same time as my spring cloud migration in the future. I kind of like the use of the bom for the spring aws library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the Spring blog https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/17/spring-cloud-2020-0-0-m1-released

> Spring Cloud AWS and Spring Cloud GCP are no longer part of the release train. They will continue to be part of Hoxton as long as it is supported – at least thru June of 2021. Spring Cloud GCP will continue on as a separate project in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform.

Comment: Does-it mean that the aws one won't be supported anymore?

Comment: As described in the blog post - we don't support it anymore. However the project as such is developed by the community

Answer (score 0):

check https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws for aws specific cloud libraries and spring boot release compatibility